# How to use Libreoffice design view and ignore PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, libreoffice

When I open a straight html file in LibreOffice design mode it displays as a Web page, great!  But if I open an existing file with HTML and PHP script the page displays as CODE, web design goes away. I have tried renaming files with both .html and .php.  I have the extention Macro Formater 4.1.1 enabled.  I also tried to enable Libreweb 1.0.7 but I get an error Failed to register package for vnd.sun.star.expand:$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/uno_packages/lu18535ea8uv4.tmp_/LibreWeb-user-1.0.7%2520(1).oxt/LibreWeb/  when I try to enable it.   What I am trying to do is the following.

Want to use design mode for my screen layout and such, and ignore PHP script so page displays as web design instead code view.  Then I use Visual Studio Code to edit all My PHP script.  Then if I make changes to PHP in visual studio code, I can then open the same file in libreoffice design view.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You really shouldn't have your code and your view in the same file. Consider restructuring your application to use a templating engine, then you can edit the template files in a WYSIWYG editor with much less hassle.

Comment: This is something I have been trying to figure out multiple times.  I am self thought on everything I do.  im good at looking at code and figuring it out if i have a quick example. Do you know a good link that talks about a templating engine.  Sounds like I need to change the bad habit that I thought myself